# Kubernetes cannot upload files larger than 1MB

Tags: kubernetes

We have a kubernetes cluster which has a dropwizard based web application  running as a service.  This application has a rest uri to upload files.  It cannot upload files larger than 1MB.  I get the following error:

```html
ERROR [2017-07-27 13:32:47,629] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: ea812501b414f0d9
! com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
!  at [Source: <html>
! <head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>
! <body bgcolor="white">
! <center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>
! <hr><center>nginx/1.11.3</center>
! </body>
! </html>
```

I have tried the suggestions given in https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/21.   I have edited the Ingress to set the proxy-body-size annotation. Also, I have tried using the configMap without any success.  we are using kubernetes version 1.5.  Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Which ingress controller are you using? Have you tried other alternatives?

Answer (score 8):

Had this on my setup as well. Two advices here:

1: switch to official kubernetes nginx ingress, it's awesome (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)

2: with the above ingress, you can add an annotation to your Ingresses to controll body size limit on per ingress basis like this :

```
annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 10m
```

works great

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: The annotation has changed for kubernetes ngnix. It is now `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 10m`

Comment: Thanks for tip - this solved the problem for me.

Comment: If I use `kubectl describe` to see the details about these pods, there is a section called "annotations". Should this annotation show up there?